# Scrapy/Python Issue: [count] does not collect entire table

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

This is a spin off of a previous XPath thread (dude told me it's not XPath related).

So I am trying to scrape this web page: http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2013.shtml for Rank, Position, Name, Age, etc.

Whenever I use:

```
item['rank'] = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]//text()')[count].extract()
item ['position'] = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]//text()')[count].extract()
```

It only gives me 5 results:

```
[{"position": "C", "rank": "1"},
{"position": "1B", "rank": "2"},
{"position": "2B", "rank": "3"},
{"position": "SS", "rank": "4"},
{"position": "3B", "rank": "5"}]
```

If I remove [count], it gives me all of the ranks and positions, but not in the correct format, and it gives me 4 duplicate lines of it (I condensed this to fit in here,there are 44):

```
{"position": ["C", "1B", "2B", "SS", "3B", "LF"], "rank": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]}
```

Here is my parser code is this will help:

```
def parse(self, response):
 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 stats = hxs.select('//div[@class="table_container"]')
 count = 0
 items = []

 for stat in stats:

     item = MlbrefItem()

     items .append(item)
     count +=1


 return items
```

I am so confused. When I did this tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/python-scrape [count] pulled all of the results. I also had no issue trying this on a different website. But this is the website I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:** Here is the actual code (ignore the comments): https://www.dropbox.com/s/rk29kotd09kioeg/mlbref_spyder.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted does not have the definition for the **MlbrefItem** class. Also, it appears from the posted code that you have incorrect indentation at the following line:

```
items.append(item)
```

You are appending an `item` object outside the for loop. This means you end up appending only the final instance of the type **MlbrefItem**. Please try the below code snippet for the `for-loop` and let us know if it works:

```
for stat in stats:

    item = MlbrefItem()

    items .append(item)
    count +=1
```

**A big edit based on discussion with AngryWhopper**

There are multiple aspects to consider here:

There are 5 divs on the page with style **table_container** The statement `stats = hxs.select('//div[@class="table_container"]')` selects all these 5 elements

The source code at the reference link provided is shown below. I have added comments to code beginning with my user name where you increment count (`count += 1`). Since this is within the for loop this happens only 5 times. Hence each of the 5 times, you end up selecting only a single element from the **list of rows** returned by the XPATH selectors for position and rank. This explains why you get only 5 pairs when you use the `count` variable within your code.

```
stats = hxs.select('//div[@class="table_container"]')
        count = 0
        items = []

        for stat in stats:

            item = MlbrefItem()

            item['rank'] = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]//text()').extract()
             item ['position'] = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]//text()').extract()

            items .append(item)
            count +=1 #PrahaladDeshpande - This count variable is incremented only 5 times since it is within the for loop

        return items
```

Without the `count` variable, you get all rows - however they are not in the correct format. Well, here you will have to to do some work. I tried the some experiments on the scrapy terminal and the below code snippet should hopefully work for you

```
stats = hxs.select('//div[@class="table_container"]')
for stat in stats:
        rank_list = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]//text()').extract()
        position_list = stat.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]//text()').extract()

         //TODO : verify that the length of the rank_list and position_list are the same. Else throw an error
         for i in range(0, len(rank_list)):
             item = MlbrefItem()
             item['rank'] = rank_list[i]
             item['position'] = position_list[i]
             items.append(item)
```

You can then return the `items` variable from your method.

Hope this points you towards a solution

Comment: My apologies Prahalad. I should have just posted the actual code file. The indentation and MlbrefItem is correct on my file, the spacing was messed up when I pasted onto here. Here is the code (please ignore the commented items, that is me experimenting to get this work): https://www.dropbox.com/s/rk29kotd09kioeg/mlbref_spyder.py

Comment: Was working on this. I could not reproduce the first issue of only 5 displays that you were talking of. I however could get the second issue you mentioned correctly. It appears that extract() method in scrapy will extract the text for *all* elements that satisfy a particular XPATH expression and put them within a list - in your case it would be ["C", "1B", "2B"...] that is mapped to "position" element and a list ["1", "2", "3", "4"...] that is mapped to "rank". I think you would have to loop through the lists provided by both the extract() calls and then create a object.

Comment: I added "from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule" and messed around with my indentions and got this to work based on your support! Thank you for your help Prahalad. I will read up on exactly what your code additions does so I can learn it. Thank you!